# Terraform - Azure - VNET Peering Conundrum

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a bit of a chicken and egg issue. Imagine multiple subscriptions, each with their own VNet. I need to peer these all with a hub which is also in its own subscription. The issue is that I am using a separate state file for each subscription.

**Issue:** I do not have one Terraform file to build the entire environment. I run an apply for each subscription. Which means I would need to run it twice.. Once for the standup for each subscription to get the VNets in place, then once again for the VNet peering after adding the module/resource to the file for peering.

This will probably cause lots of problems. Especially if I run a destroy/re-apply.

Is there a better way of doing this? If it were one file for the entire environment, Terraform would make sure the VNets were there OR I could use a 'depends_on' attribute. But, the way I'm doing this might break everything.

**Thoughts:**

- Do peering OUTSIDE of Terraform
- Use a separate Terraform state file for peering - probably a really bad idea
- Do a two step process; setup subscription/Vnet in one run and peering in a second - probably won't work very well
- Something I'm missing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have deployed each VNet in each subscription, I think you can do a two-step process: setup subscription/Vnet in one run and peering in a second. The terraform peering configuration will like [this](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/1253#issuecomment-427984944), use `alias` for one specific subscription that you will refer to, use `data` to query the existing resources in each subscription. Ensure that the Service Principal you're using either has permissions to both Subscriptions or a different Service Principal is used for each Provider block (with the associated permissions).

For example,

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version         = "xxx"
  tenant_id       = "aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa"
  subscription_id = "aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa"
  client_id       = "aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa"
  client_secret   = "aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa"
  alias           = "dev"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  version         = "xxx"
  tenant_id       = "bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb"
  subscription_id = "bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb"
  client_id       = "bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb"
  client_secret   = "bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb"
  alias           = "test"
}

data "azurerm_virtual_network" "dev" {
  name                = "dev-network"
  resource_group_name = "dev-network-rg"
  provider            = "azurerm.dev"
}

data "azurerm_virtual_network" "test" {
  name                = "test-network"
  resource_group_name = "test-network-rg"
  provider            = "azurerm.test"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "dev-to-test" {
  name                         = "dev-to-test"
  resource_group_name          = "${data.azurerm_virtual_network.test.resource_group_name}"
  virtual_network_name         = "${data.azurerm_virtual_network.test.name}"
  remote_virtual_network_id    = "${data.azurerm_virtual_network.test.id}"
  allow_virtual_network_access = true
  allow_forwarded_traffic      = true
  provider                     = "azurerm.dev"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "test-to-dev" {
  name                         = "test-to-dev"
  resource_group_name          = "${data.azurerm_virtual_network.dev.resource_group_name}"
  virtual_network_name         = "${data.azurerm_virtual_network.dev.name}"
  remote_virtual_network_id    = "${data.azurerm_virtual_network.dev.id}"
  allow_virtual_network_access = true
  allow_forwarded_traffic      = true
  provider                     = "azurerm.test"
}
```

If you are using the Azure CLI auth, you could refer to [this](https://gist.github.com/tombuildsstuff/2c1645df77fd7b867248cb2bd8fdb2b2).

Alternatively, as you thought, you could try to use a `depends_on` attribute in the `azurerm_virtual_network_peering` block refer to [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/terraform/terraform-hub-spoke-spoke-network#declare-the-two-spoke-networks).

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "spoke1-vnet" {
  provider            = "azurerm.dev"
  name                = "spoke1-vnet"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.spoke1-vnet-rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.spoke1-vnet-rg.name
  address_space       = ["10.1.0.0/16"]

}
resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "spoke1-hub-peer" {
  provider                  = "azurerm.dev"
  name                      = "spoke1-hub-peer"
  resource_group_name       = azurerm_resource_group.spoke1-vnet-rg.name
  virtual_network_name      = azurerm_virtual_network.spoke1-vnet.name
  remote_virtual_network_id = azurerm_virtual_network.hub-vnet.id

  allow_virtual_network_access = true
  allow_forwarded_traffic = true
  allow_gateway_transit   = false
  use_remote_gateways     = true
  depends_on = ["azurerm_virtual_network.spoke1-vnet", "azurerm_virtual_network.hub-vnet" , "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway.hub-vnet-gateway"]
}
```

For more information, you could refer to this [blog1](https://samcogan.com/deploying-to-multiple-azure-subscriptions-with-terraform/) and [blog2](https://azurecitadel.com/automation/terraform/lab5/) for deploying to multiple subscriptions with terraform.

Comment: Great info. The only issue is that I have a separate state file for each subscription. This allows each to be independent. Because of that 'depends_on' won't work. I could have a 'peering' state file and everything else in another state file. Right now, I'm doing peering with Python after deployment of the TF elements.

Comment: Just doing some reading and I'm learning about Terraform Workspaces. Could this address this issue?

Comment: Yes, Terraform workspace is like a working environment. It could isolate their state. You can use `terraform workspace new` to create a new workspace and use `terraform workspace select` to switch workspaces. When the VNets are created in each subscription and in each workspace, you can create VNet peering in a separate state file later as the first example in my reply.

Comment: Any process in the question?

Comment: Didn't forget about this. Trying it out I'm finding that workspaces don't work the way that I expected... at least I'm not seeing it yet. It wants to take an already existing .tf file and apply it with a different state file. So I could pass different variables into it and have it be a different environment BUT it is based off the same .tf configuration as the 'default' workspace. Looks like I'll have to do whole different configuraiton/state file.

Comment: Yes, It seems you need to rebuild the infrastructure configuration files. This is a clear way.